# Increase predict_proba precision in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, precision

Can I set a higher precision  on the results given by the method predict_proba from sklearn?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities returned by `predict_proba` are `float`:

```
prediction_probs = classifier.predict_proba(a_test) 

type(prediction_probs[1][1])
```

returns:

```
numpy.float64
```

and

```
prediction_probs[1][1]
```

returns:

```
0.40000000000000002
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put a condition after predict_proba so that samples are predicted positive only if the probabilty exceeds your custom threshold

```
custom_threshold = .9
y_test_pred = classifier.predict_proba(x_test) > custom_threshold
```

you can choose an appropriate threshold for new unseen samples, so that it reflects your desired precision, by looking at `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve` on your test set